# Windows Installer not working?

Tags: windows, installer, packages

Today I brought an iPad 2 and my computer said that to plug the iPad into my computer I needed the newest version of iTunes. I downloaded the installer and when it got to the end of the set up, it said *There is a problem with this Windows installer package*. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the previous installer, clean the computer cache, temp files, and other junk data (`cleanmgr.exe`), then re-download the installer.

Answer (score 0):

When it says there's a problem with *this* windows installer package it usually means that particular installer is corrupt or has issues.

The first step is to download the installer again from the Apple website and try running the installer again.

Comment: *> When it says there's a problem with this windows installer package it usually means that particular installer is corrupt or has issues.* Either that or Windows Installer. If the MSIServer is broken, then *everything* misleadingly complains like that.